# Loading Value of Input into Slider Options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the variable "value" in my slider plugin to be the integer value of a input in the form:

```
$(function () {
  $("#calcSlider").slider({ 
    min: 0,
    max: 90,
    step: 5,
    value: /* ACCESS HERE!!!!!! */,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $("#calcSup").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```

I need `value:` to be the value in `calcSup` or `${form.calcSup}`, but that is a string. I need it parsed to a int:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="calcSup" 
       name="calcSup" 
       value="${form.calcSup}" 
       size="3" 
       readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the parseInt function, more details can be found here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

```
$(function () {
$("#calcSlider").slider({ min: 0,
                          max: 90,
                          step: 5,
                          value: parseInt($('input#calcSup').val()),
                          slide: function (event, ui) {
                              $("#calcSup").val(ui.value);
                          }
                       });
                    });

<input type="text" id="calcSup" name="calcSup" value="${form.calcSup}" size="3" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: I know, the answer to your problem is simple. Good luck!

Comment: The `parseInt` method is lacking a radix, which would convert something like "023" to 19. `parseInt` interprets strings with leading-zeroes as base-8 (with the exception of `0x`, being 16).

Comment: why would I have a leading 0?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to parse the value to an integer, don't forget to include the radix so it doesn't wind up getting confused for base-8 or something.

```
$("#mySlider").slider({
  // Set initial value to that of <input type="text" id="bar" value="23" />
  value: parseInt( $("#bar").val(), 10 ),
  // Update <input type="text" id="foo" /> anytime we slide
  slide: function ( event, ui ) {
    $("#foo").val(ui.value);
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/oceqab/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
$(function () {
    $("#calcSlider").slider({ min: 0,
                          max: 90,
                          step: 5,
                          value: parseInt($("#calcSup").val()),
                          slide: function (event, ui) {
                              $("#calcSup").val(ui.value);
                          }
    });
});
```